# How to autowire default XmlMapper in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, xmlmapper

I'm having some issues autowiring the default Jackson `XmlMapper` in one of my Spring Boot projects. I've created a simple example project that illustrates this.

What I'm doing here is roughly based on this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-write-an-xml-rest-service

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

From pom.xml

```
<!-- ... -->

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- ... -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- ... -->
```

The main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Demo POJO, not specifying `@XmlRootElement`, so it won't use JAXB:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Demo {
    private String stringProperty;
    private int intProperty;
    public String getStringProperty() {
        return stringProperty;
    }
    public void setStringProperty(String stringProperty) {
        this.stringProperty = stringProperty;
    }
    public int getIntProperty() {
        return intProperty;
    }
    public void setIntProperty(int intProperty) {
        this.intProperty = intProperty;
    }
}
```

The Demo Controller:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @Autowired 
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    // @Autowired 
    // private XmlMapper xmlMapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Demo getDemo() {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setStringProperty("Hello world!");
        demo.setIntProperty(42);
        return demo;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine the way it is, depending on `Accept` headers, either JSON or XML will be returned.

I can easily autowire the default `ObjectMapper` configured by Spring Boot. So far so good.

If I comment in the autowiring of the `XmlMapper` I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 18 more
```

Any idea why this is? I would have assumed it to work the same way as the `ObjectMapper`. Just to clarify, I *don't* want to customise the mappers, I simply want a reference to the default ones created by Spring Boot.

Comment: Probably Spring Boot not contains XmlMapper in IoC container, try to inject bean first.

Comment: I know I can create my own XmlMapper, but I want the default one, the one that is actually being used for mapping a class to Xml in the response body, which is working correctly right now, so there must be an XmlMapper somewhere right? @kris14an

Comment: I've solved the problem much simpler. I simply don't map the XmlMapper. I just construct it in the method block. Possibly it won't work if the xml to process is too complex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring Boot does not expose the `XmlMapper` as a bean as it would conflict with the `ObjectMapper` bean that's used for JSON mapping (Jackson's `XmlMapper` is a subclass of Jackson's `ObjectMapper`).

Comment: This answers the question of course. An implied next question would have been, "can I get at the XmlMapper some other way?", and I've found that you can autowire `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` instead and get the `XmlMapper` via `.getObjectMapper()`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing with the latest Spring-Boot, but finding that I cannot Autowire the ObjectMapper or the MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.  Both result in "No qualifying bean of type" errors.

Comment: My IDE told me I had that same problem ("No qualifying bean of type"), but when running the code all is fine...

Answer (score 25):

Based on the answer by @Andy Wilkinson I did some more digging and found a way to get at what I wanted. Spring Boot does not expose the `XmlMapper` as a Bean but it does expose the message converter it is used in, which is `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`. So I could auto-wire that bean and get the `ObjectMapper` (which is now an `XmlMapper`) from it.

The Demo Controller from my question now looks like this:

```java
    @RestController
    public class DemoController {
        @Autowired 
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
        @Autowired
        private MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Demo getDemo() {
            Demo demo = new Demo();
            demo.setStringProperty("Hello world!");
            demo.setIntProperty(42);
            ObjectMapper xmlMapper = xmlConverter.getObjectMapper();
            return demo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing with the latest Spring-Boot, but finding that I cannot Autowire the ObjectMapper or the MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter. Both result in "No qualifying bean of type" errors.

Comment: @robross0606 Check that you have the dependencies in the pom.xml in the question.

Comment: Already checked that.  I'm using Gradle for dependency management, but  have confirmed that I have all the same dependencies as listed above in your Maven POM.

Comment: @robross0606 Not sure then, I created that minimal project specifically for this question, there is no more too it. I'm not familiar with gradle. Maybe a new question?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing so:

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter) {
    return (XmlMapper) converter.getObjectMapper();
}
```

And

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter converter) {
    return converter.getObjectMapper();
}
```

If you want support for JSON and XML then you should register those beans by yourself with BeanFactoryPostProcessor method described in [How to create multiple beans of same type according to configuration in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272472/how-to-create-multiple-beans-of-same-type-according-to-configuration-in-spring?rq=1)