# How to create multiple beans of same type according to configuration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a specified number of beans of a same type in Spring.

I've tried:

```
@Bean(name = "beanList")
public List<MyBean> beanList(
        @Value("${number:1}") int number
        ) {
    List<MyBean> beanList = new ArrayList<>(number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        beanList.add(new MyBean());
    }
    return beanList;
}
```

But this is not what expected.

In this way, the bean "beanList" is maintained by spring context, instead of it's elements, so I can't **specify a name and init method or destroy method for each element** in the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using an ObjectPool instead?

Comment: ObjectPool is not what I'm expecting because in fact I want to create multiple threads using these beans, and they're not *resources*, each of these beans is different and no bean could be *idle*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could have a look at [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html), I tried with following code and it's working just fine, `Bean`s depends on `MyBean` could also be `autowire`d:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("register my bean: " + i);
            beanFactory.registerSingleton("bean-" + i, new MyBean("MyBean-" + i));
        }
    }
}
```

Since you have complete control of creation process of `MyBean` instance, you can simply pass other beans in through constructor if it's necessary. Hope this could be helpful to you :-)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to specify init method or destroy method for each bean?

Comment: @JuanZhong, sorry for late response, I think you can declare `init` and `destroy` for `MyBean` and overwrite/implement them when you `new` each bean, sorry to say but I failed to make annotation `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` work :'(. Maybe I missed something simple or got the wrong way to do this. Anyway, I asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279810/spring-predestroy-and-postconstruct-is-not-working-when-register-bean-using-be for this issue, good choice to learn and let's wait to see how other people will say.

Comment: I found a problem of `registerSingleton`, these beans could not be enhanced by spring, which means spring-aop won't intercept methods of these beans @shizhz

Comment: According to the following answer, we cannot pass other beans in this constructor because the BeanFactoryPostProcessor is called before other beans are actually instantiated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455536/beanfactorypostprocessor-and-beanpostprocessor-in-lifecycle-events/30456202