# Creating multiple Bean instances with different things autowired in

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get Spring Boot dependency injection to allow me to do the following:

```kotlin
interface MyBean

@Component
class MyBeanA : MyBean

@Component
class MyBeanB : MyBean

@Component
class MyBeanConsumer(myBean: MyBean)
```

Here, Spring complains that there are multiple beans of type `MyBean`. I would like it to create two instances of `MyBeanConsumer`. One with `MyBeanA` and one with `MyBeanB`. I need to do this for a number of beans, so I'm trying to avoid boilerplate configuration classes like this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyBeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun consumers(myBeans: List<MyBean>) = myBeans.map { MyBeanConsumer(it) }
}
```

Is this possible in Spring?

Comment: Then you will have multiple instance of `MyBeanConsumer`. How do you want to use them. I mean somewhere in your program you want to use one of them and somewhere the other one? or you want to iterate through them and do something.

Comment: Yes, having multiple instances is the plan. I want to use them as a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Qualifier` annotation and specify the name of the bean requested.

you can visit this
[Spring @Autowired and @Qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830548/spring-autowired-and-qualifier/48134386)

Comment: This does not answer the question. I do not want one instance with a qualified parameter. I want an instance per possible parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If everywhere in your program you want to inject them as List of beans you can go with this approach.

```
@Configuration public MyConfigurationClass {
        
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("mylist")
        public List<MyType> configure() {
            //create your dynamical list here
        }
 }
```

But if you want to use them as individual bean somewhere in your program and also you want to inject all of them as a List somewhere else you can do that this way:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("register my bean: " + i);
            beanFactory.registerSingleton("bean-" + i, new MyBean("MyBean-" + i));
        }
    }
```

Read the following answer for further detail:
[How to create multiple beans of same type according to configuration in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272472/how-to-create-multiple-beans-of-same-type-according-to-configuration-in-spring)

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid: Boilerplate for each of these cases. I stated this in the question.